# Sublime Text 3 FileBrowser plugin: how to open in new tab by default

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, file-browser

I am using the Sublime Text 3 FileBrowser for file navigation on keyboard.

While usually I open files in new tabs, with FileBrowser, it opens 
On the official documentation (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileBrowser), it says:

> Open all marked items in new tabs `⌘+enter / ctrl+enter`

So when I open a file on 'Enter', it will open in the same split pane as the 
[image]
[image]
I want to change this behavior

So I go to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> FileBrowser ->`

1. `Settings - Default`
2. `Key Bindings - Default (Common)`

to look for options I can override in user settings. However, nothing seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow found an answer while posting the question, so I throw it out first and look for any better ways from the community.

By setting an open directory command in the `Key Bindings`, it reverts to opening in a new tab as by default.(I set it as a user setting for easier management: `Preferences -> Package Settings -> FileBrowser -> Key Bindings - User`)

(from the official package page: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileBrowser)

```
[
    {
    "keys": ["f1"],
    "command": "dired",
    "args": {
      "immediate": true,
      "single_pane": true,
      "other_group": "left",
        }
    }
]
```

Of course, you can bind the `"dired"` command to any other suitable key, and tweak other behaviors such as putting it left or right.

One thing to note is that this must not be used with

```
{
  "keys": ["enter"],
  "command": "dired_select", "args": {"and_close": true},
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.dired" },
    { "key": "setting.dired_rename_mode", "operand": false }
  ]
}
```

Maybe there are ways to tweak around, so I can both open in new tab on "Enter", and let the browser close automatically after selection. For now, I'm settled for closing it with `F1`.